# failed to add box shadow style to an element in angular5

Tags: angular5

I am trying to create a simple app in angular5. When the user presses the button I trying to add/remove the box shadow effect of the button element.

```
<div class="btnClutch" #clBtn [style.boxShadow]="clutchBtnShakeEffect  ? null : '0px 8px B73835'">
        <div class="clutchBtn"></div>
        <img src="/assets/clutchpng" class="btnClutchImg">
      </div>
```

I am trying to add boxshadow effect in the above format,but it's not working.what i missed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle *clutchBtnShakeEffect* flag on every click as below.

```
<div class="btnClutch" #clBtn 
     (click)="clutchBtnShakeEffect = !clutchBtnShakeEffect"
     [style.boxShadow]="clutchBtnShakeEffect ? null : '0px 8px B73835'">
    <div class="clutchBtn"></div>
    <img src="/assets/clutchpng" class="btnClutchImg">
</div>`enter code here`
```